# Protractor error on npm 3.x

Tags: selenium, protractor

I faced an issue when migrated from npm 2.10.0 to third version. I have no errors after npm install and everything seems ok, but I have errors when I try to run protractor tests. I got this error:
StaleElementReferenceError: {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache" ...
For phantom.js

And this error: 
 StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
For chrome.

protractor version is 2.1.0
node is 4.2.2
npm is 3.4.0

If I downgrade npm to 2.10.0 and reinstall packages - everything works fine.

Does anybody has the same issue?